# Is it possible to use <iframe> to show 100% of another website on my site?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Like the title states is it possible to use  to show 100% of another website on my site? Without any of the contents from my own site showing?

I tried using a code like this,

```
<iframe src="google.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

But my own site is still showing up below the  contents when it runs out. Please help thanks.

Comment: `%` is a relative measurement unit; when you use it in an element, you need to know what's around it. Can you show also include all its parents?

Answer (score 1):

You may try with these css codes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.premierleague.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: i dont think i can put in css code is it possible using just html code?

Comment: If you can edit html file then you can put below css code into your html.